# Linking protobuf library with code (Google protocol buffers)

Tags: linker, protocol-buffers

I am getting linking error when I try to compile a test code.
I'm using cygwin on windows 7.
Initial steps like ./configure, make, make test & make install went fine

I'm also able to generate .pb.cc and .pb.h with protoc command.

But when I try to compile my test code, it gets many linking errors. I'm sure those errors are because it is unable to link to library.

Cygwin has protobuf static library and linking library in /usr/local/lib 
. include files are present in /usr/local/include

I tried with -lprotobuf, but it returns error saying -lprotobuf not found

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It hard to say what the problem is since you don't include neither the makefile nor the errors, but my guess is that the path `/usr/local/lib` is not included in the search path when looking for libraries.

Try adding `-L/usr/local/lib` before `-lprotobuf`.