# Getting protobuf linking errors even after seemingly linking protobuf libraries (C++)

Tags: c++, linker, g++, c++14, protocol-buffers

I am doing a project in which I am using protobuf. I have version 3.1.0 installed.

I wrote a program to test serialization in protobuf which looks like this

```
// This file exists to facilitate testing

//MIST.cpp

//#include <asio.hpp>
#include <Task.hpp> //user defined, not relevant
#include <MIST.hpp> //user defined, not relevant
#include <ReceiveData.hpp> //user defined, not relevant
#include <MIST.pb.h> //protobuf file made from protoc

int main() {
    /*MIST::ReceiveData receiveObj;
    std::string s = receiveObj.receive<64>();
    std::cout << "Message received: '" << s << "'" << std::endl;*/

    ProtobufMIST::Task taskObj;
    taskObj.set_task_name("The Best Task");
    taskObj.set_task_id("7");

    std::string* message;
    if(!taskObj.SerializeToString(message))
        std::cout << "Task '" << taskObj.task_name() << "'" << " not serialized successfully\n";
    else
        std::cout << message << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I compiled it with a build script. The underlying command is `g++ std=c++1y [link include files] -lpthread MIST.cpp -lprotobuf -o a.o`

This command exits successfully.

I then try to link `a.o` with the command `g++ a.o -std=c++1y -L/usr/local/lib/ -lprotobuf -o a` and I get the following error

```
a.o: In function `main':
MIST.cpp:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `ProtobufMIST::Task::Task()'
MIST.cpp:(.text+0x55): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::MessageLite::SerializeToString(std::string*) const'
MIST.cpp:(.text+0xd0): undefined reference to `ProtobufMIST::Task::~Task()'
MIST.cpp:(.text+0xf2): undefined reference to `ProtobufMIST::Task::~Task()'
a.o: In function `google::protobuf::internal::GetEmptyStringAlreadyInited()':

MIST.cpp:(.text._ZN6google8protobuf8internal27GetEmptyStringAlreadyInitedEv[_ZN6google8protobuf8internal27GetEmptyStringAlreadyInitedEv]+0x5): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::fixed_address_empty_string'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm not sure how there can be undefined references to include files I have already compiled with, or how there can be undefined references to protobuf when I've included both -L/usr/local/lib and -lprotobuf. I'm stumped as to how to what could be the problem.

For reference, I have tried to implement these solutions little success

[problems with linking protobuf library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14669299/problems-with-linking-protobuf-library)

[Linking protobuf library with code (Google protocol buffers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207053/linking-protobuf-library-with-code-google-protocol-buffers)

[Can't compile example from google protocol buffers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404027/cant-compile-example-from-google-protocol-buffers)

Running Kubuntu 16.10 on a virtual machine. Host is Windows 10.

Comment: As an update: I reinstalled protobuf and many of the errors have disappeared, the error now reads

    a.o: In function `main':
    MIST.cpp:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `ProtobufMIST::Task::Task()'
    MIST.cpp:(.text+0xd0): undefined reference to `ProtobufMIST::Task::~Task()'
    MIST.cpp:(.text+0xf2): undefined reference to `ProtobufMIST::Task::~Task()'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: OK so the issue ultimately was that I, like an idiot, wasn't actually linking anything when compiling. I had to compile the generated protobuf files into a .o and compile it with a.o.

Comment: Hi @CyberDork34. Can you explain your solution with the build command?

Answer (score -1):

Compile the .pb.cc file into a .o file and link it with the main program, this should solve the issue.