# Pybind11 - ImportError: .../pybindx.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZN6google8protobuf8internal26fixed_address_empty_stringB5cxx11E

Tags: python, c++11, protocol-buffers, pybind11, pybinding

I wrote some binding code to bind C++ code with python in `pybindx.cpp` file. I want to call some functions (implemented in C++) using python. When I use `python setup.py build_ext` command, the `.so` file `./build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/pybindx.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` is getting created, but when I try to import(`import pybindx`) in `test.py` to call binded functions, It gives the following error:

```
ImportError: <path-to-.so-file>/pybindx.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZN6google8protobuf8internal26fixed_address_empty_stringB5cxx11E
```

I have added <path-to-.so-file> to `PYTHONPATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

My `setup.py` file contains following code:

```
import os, sys
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from distutils import sysconfig

cpp_args = ['-std=c++11']

ext_modules = [
    Extension(
        'pybindx',
        ['class1.cpp', 'class2.cpp', 'base_class1.cpp', 'base_class2.cpp', 'pybindx.cpp'],
        include_dirs=['paths/to/include/header/files', 'path/to/protobuf/include'],
        language='c++',
        extra_compile_args = cpp_args,
    ),
]
setup(
    name='pybindx',
    version='0.0.1',
    author='xxxxx',
    author_email='xxxxx',
    description='desc',
    ext_modules=ext_modules,
)
```

Where, `class1.cpp`, `class2.cpp`, `base_class1.cpp`, `base_class2.cpp` are the files having implementation of classes and functions which I want to bind with python.

I am new to `pybind11`, can someone help me with this?
Thanks!

I tried writing small example code **without protobuf**, where I am able to call the C++ function using `test.py`, but here I want to use protobuf.

Comment: It looks like your code needs protobuf. So far you've only added include_dir, so it compiles. But you need to add library_dirs and libraries to `Extension` arguments to specify where the protobuf lib/so are.

Comment: @0x26res I tried adding  library_dirs=['path/to/protobuf.so'] and libraries=['path/to/libs'] or ['path/to/protobuf.so'], but getting the same error. I hope this is the correct way to add library_dirs and libraries. What else can be the issue?

Comment: You will also need to add something like `extra_link_args=['-lprotobuf']`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207053/linking-protobuf-library-with-code-google-protocol-buffers)

Comment: library_dirs should be `["path/to/"] (directories) and libraries should be `["protobuf"]` (the name of the library file without the `lib` prefix or `.so` extension

Comment: 1. library_dirs=['path/to/protobuf/dir'], libraries=['protobuf']  \\
2. extra_link_args=['-lprotobuf'] \\

I tried 1. and 2. both individually and combined also, Nothing is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyways, fixed it. I Used `Makefile` rather than `setup.py`. I have to link static `libprotobuf.a` with my `pybindx.so`.
Added following command with other required commands in Makefile:

`g++ -shared -fPIC ./build/*.o <path-to-static-protobuf>/libprotobuf.a -o pybindx.so`

Where, `*.o` are the object files created using some command(s) in `Makefile`.